# Scraping a Website only for its Text

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am helping remodel a website and was wondering if it was possible to scrape just the Text out of the entire site. Doing a page one at a time using **DATA SCRAPER** is possible but there is hundreds of pages that need to be worked on. Is there a way to get them all in one scrape? Or further suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there is a standalone program called HTTrack (https://www.httrack.com/) that will download an entire website to your local computer. I've used it successfully in the past when I need to grab everything.

Edit: This is my first answer on stackoverflow. Why was this voted down? I'd like to know so I don't do it again.

Comment: No idea why you were voted down, but you do understand for the most part. The problem is the way the site was written. I will give httrack a go and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

For those who landed here,

If you want to scrape an entire website and get only its text content, you can use scrapy.

The below github repository does the job.

https://github.com/mnk-reddy/Website-Crawler

You can change the depth and max pages to crawl using the DEPTH_LIMIT and CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT in settings.py

The output is saved as a csv file with the url and text content in each record. Note this scarpes only the domain given to it. Hyperlinks to other domains are not scraped.